# Books that cover polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Is there a book that goes over polynomials and their properties, operations on polynomials, divisibility and division of polynomials by other polynomials, roots(complex or real), factorization, irreducible polynomials, rational fractions, poles and partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Like high-school sort of level?

Comment: Any Abstract algebra book does that.

Comment: One of my favorite books: Polynomials by Edward Barbeau.

Comment: @will m I just started college so I guess college undergrad

Comment: @Phicar Exactly. It is also mentioned in the duplicate.

Comment: How I learned was through an abstract algebra book (e.g. Abstract Algebra by Robert Ash). But I am unsure of any book that focuses solely on polynomials.